# jquery ui dialog box with youtube video dissapears after window close

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've been using jquery ui's dialog popup box to put a youtube video in it....

its working great but what i want is when the user hits play on the you tube video...if then they click the x to close out of the box.......the video stops playing but when i reopen the box again the box is empty

So my QUESTION is how can i do it so that when the user closes out of the box the video stops playing and they can reopen the box to see the video again

heres the html

```
  <h2 class="demoHeaders">Dialog</h2>
  <p><a href="#" id="dialog-link" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-          icon ui-icon-newwin"></span>Open Dialog</a></p>

   <!-- ui-dialog -->
   <div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/7Lmxmh9zDEk"   frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
   </div>
```

heres the jquery

```
$(function() {


    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 400,
        buttons: [
            {
                text: "Ok",
                click: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            },
            {
                text: "Cancel",
                click: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        ]
    });

    // Link to open the dialog
    $( "#dialog-link" ).click(function( event ) {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
        event.preventDefault();
    });

            $(".ui-icon-closethick").click (event) ->
        event.preventDefault()
       $("#video").remove()
```

Heres the link to the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QBKzH/1/

thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I grabbed the url from my embed, and attaching it on event click, and detaching it on modal close. You can do the same thing in your iframe I believe.

Give an id to your iframe

`<iframe id="video" />` or something

```
$('#dialog-link').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

            // Set video url
    var videoSourceLink = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/7Lmxmh9zDEk';

            // Attach video link
    $('#video').attr('src', videoSourceLink);

    $('#dialog').dialog({
        modal: true,
        width:658,
        height:404,
        resizable: false,
        open: function(){
            $('.ui-widget-overlay').bind('click',function(){
                $('#video').removeAttr('src');  
                $('<don't remember what this select is').dialog('close');                
            });
        }                   
    });
});
```